# Show that $|d(x, Y ) − d(y, X)| \leq |x − y|, \forall x \in X\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ and $y \in Y\subset\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: real-analysis

I must show that $|d(x, Y ) − d(y, X)| \leq |x − y|, \forall x \in X\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ and $y \in Y\subset\mathbb{R}^N$

So I took $\overline x\in \overline X$ and $\overline y\in \overline Y$, such as $d(x,Y)=|x-\overline y|$ and $d(y,X)=|y-\overline x|$

And did $d(x,Y) = |x-\overline y|=|x-\overline y +\overline x - \overline x + y -
 y|\leq|-\overline x + y|+|x-y+\overline x-\overline y|=d(y,X) + |x-y+\overline x-\overline y|$

Similarly, $d(y,X) \leq d(x,Y)+|x-y+\overline x-\overline y|$

I don't know how to get rid of the $\overline x-\overline y$

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is d an arbitrary metric? Or d is the absolute value metric?

Comment: d is the euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  $d(x,Y) \le d(x,y) \le d(x,y) + d(y,X)$ and $d(y,X) \leq d(y,x) \le d(y,x)+d(x,Y)$ give you what you want.

Comment: Sorry. I  missed the bar.

Comment: @BrunoMazeto I know the comment was directed at the answerer

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $d(x,Y)=\inf_{y \in Y}d(x,y)$ and I am just adding another non negative number to it

Comment: feel free to change it back but I think it's better like this.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You thought I just wrote it like that?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question